# Python Eve allow_unknown=True and projection (exclusion)

Tags: python, mongodb, eve

I have a collection with non well defined schema. It is read-only and I am using python-eve with the option `allow_unknown=True`, so that it returns the whole documents even if they do not match the (non-existent) schema.

Some documents in the collection contain a heavy field named `d`:

```
{
   '_id': '...',
   'date': '2020-10-10',
   'd': {...}
}
```

The projection: `http://url/?projection={"d":0}` basically does nothing. The returned documents come with the field `d`. The expected behavior is to exclude the field `d` and include everything else.

The opposite behaviour `http://url/?projection={"d":1}` works well and excludes all except the field `d`.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

No, you're right, I've implemented your case and got exactly what you say. The problem is that when you set `allow_unknown` to `True`, the projection is disabled.

After more investigating, found this issue on GitHub:

https://github.com/pyeve/eve/issues/1187

I think for now you should just oppositely use projection.